# Block cumulative size is too big

Tags: error-log, blocksize

I'm getting this error after upgrading to 0.10.3:

src/cryptonote_basic/cryptonote_basic_impl.cpp:114  Block cumulative size is too big: 165421791, expected less than 132478

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This issue was fixed in a minor point release 0.10.3.1:

> The 0.10.3.1 point release disables a portion of the server-side hash
>   cache that was preventing a small subset of nodes from syncing.

https://github.com/monero-project/monero/releases/tag/v0.10.3.1

Comment: After you update, if monerod is still stuck on a block, I used this to get based the sticking block: ./monero-blockchain-import --pop-blocks 500